# AppCenter iOS crash report - could not understand what caused the crash

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash, visual-studio-app-center

I received an unsymbolicated crash report on appcenter.

I uploaded the dsym file to get the stack trace. Got the stack trace but couldn't understand what caused the crash.

It looks like it is something related to iOS UI.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    MAIN THREAD - CRASHED
    libobjc.A.dylib
    objc_msgSend
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool)
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool)
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool)
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool)
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool)
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::update_added_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CA::Layer*, unsigned int)
    QuartzCore
    CA::Layer::insert_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CALayer*, unsigned long)
    QuartzCore
    -[CALayer addSublayer:]
    UIKitCore
    -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
    UIKitCore
    -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]
    UIKitCore
    +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
    UIKitCore
    -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]
    UIKitCore
    +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
    UIKitCore
    +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
    UIKitCore
    -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:]
    UIKitCore
    -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]
    UIKitCore
    _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
    UIKitCore
    _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
    UIKitCore
    _afterCACommitHandler
    CoreFoundation
    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
    CoreFoundation
    __CFRunLoopDoObservers
    CoreFoundation
    __CFRunLoopRun
    CoreFoundation
    CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    GraphicsServices
    GSEventRunModal
    UIKitCore
    UIApplicationMain
    SENSE.iOS
    wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr
    SENSE.iOS
    UIApplication.cs:86
    SENSE.iOS
    UIApplication.cs:65
    SENSE.iOS
    Main.cs:9
    SENSE.iOS
    wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
    SENSE.iOS
    mono_jit_runtime_invoke mini-runtime.c:3119
    SENSE.iOS
    mono_runtime_invoke_checked object.c:2960
    SENSE.iOS
    mono_runtime_exec_main_checked object.c:0
    SENSE.iOS
    mono_jit_exec driver.g.c:1236
    SENSE.iOS
    xamarin_main monotouch-main.m:484
    SENSE.iOS
    main main.m:203
    libdyld.dylib
    start
```

Comment: Hard to get something out of this trace. Can you debug the app? If so, try wrapping the `InitializeComponent` calls in your code behinds with try-catches and a breakpoint on them. Sometimes it throw exceptions but nothing is logged or exposed for some reason.

Comment: Is it from appcenter crash log files? if not download the logs zip